# Karate API Testing - verify if "retriever" breed is within the list

Tags: karate

I am testing a public API that lists all types of breeds.

> 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all'

Within the response I need to verify if "retriever" breed is within the list. My feature file looks like this

**Feature: Testing a REST API**

```
Scenario: Testing valid GET endpoint
Given url 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all'
When method GET
Then status 200
And print response
And match response.message contains 'retriever'
```

However I get the following error:

> com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: path: $.message, actual:
>   {affenpinscher=[], african=[], airedale=[], akita=[], appenzeller=[],
>   basenji=[], beagle=[], bluetick=[], borzoi=[], bouvier=[], boxer=[],
>   brabancon=[], briard=[], bulldog=["boston","french"],
>   bullterrier=["staffordshire"], cairn=[], cattledog=["australian"],
>   chihuahua=[], chow=[], clumber=[], cockapoo=[], collie=["border"],
>   coonhound=[], corgi=["cardigan"], cotondetulear=[], dachshund=[],
>   dalmatian=[], dane=["great"], deerhound=["scottish"], dhole=[],
>   dingo=[], doberman=[], elkhound=["norwegian"], entlebucher=[],
>   eskimo=[], frise=["bichon"], germanshepherd=[], greyhound=["italian"],
>   groenendael=[],
>   hound=["afghan","basset","blood","english","ibizan","walker"],
>   husky=[], keeshond=[], kelpie=[], komondor=[], kuvasz=[], labrador=[],
>   leonberg=[], lhasa=[], malamute=[], malinois=[], maltese=[],
>   mastiff=["bull","tibetan"], mexicanhairless=[], mix=[],
>   mountain=["bernese","swiss"], newfoundland=[], otterhound=[],
>   papillon=[], pekinese=[], pembroke=[], pinscher=["miniature"],
>   pointer=["german","germanlonghair"], pomeranian=[],
>   poodle=["miniature","standard","toy"], pug=[], puggle=[], pyrenees=[],
>   redbone=[], retriever=["chesapeake","curly","flatcoated","golden"],
>   ridgeback=["rhodesian"], rottweiler=[], saluki=[], samoyed=[],
>   schipperke=[], schnauzer=["giant","miniature"],
>   setter=["english","gordon","irish"], sheepdog=["english","shetland"],
>   shiba=[], shihtzu=[],
>   spaniel=["blenheim","brittany","cocker","irish","japanese","sussex","welsh"], springer=["english"], stbernard=[],
>   terrier=["american","australian","bedlington","border","dandie","fox","irish","kerryblue","lakeland","norfolk","norwich","patterdale","russell","scottish","sealyham","silky","tibetan","toy","westhighland","wheaten","yorkshire"],
>   vizsla=[], weimaraner=[], whippet=[], wolfhound=["irish"]}, expected:
>   'retriever', reason: actual value is not a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the response structure carefully. These will work:

```
And match response.message contains { retriever: '#array' }
And match response.message.retriever == ['chesapeake', 'curly', 'flatcoated', 'golden']
```

Do read the documentation and examples.

Comment: Can you share a link where I can find the documentation and examples please